# Alter Table Column Type Does not Work in Aster - I am Probably Screwing It Up

Tags: sql, casting, int, random-forest, aster

I am using Aster as there are some groovy Random Forest Functions to use. My dependent, or response variable, is a boolean dichotomous variable; a 0 or 1.

When I run it through the Random Forest Function of choice it creates a predicted value of the response variable. It calls this variable prediction and it automatically creates it as a VARCHAR(REALLY BIG INTEGER IN HERE).

To do some of my calculations I simply wish to cast or convert it to an integer from a string. All of the resulting character strings are either a 0 or a 1:

```
alter table a0q892.zf_predict alter column prediction int;
```

does not work. The error message I receive is:

```
Executed as Single statement.
Failed [34 : 42000] [AsterData][ASTERJDBCDSII](34) ERROR: syntax error at or near "int" ()
```

I am pretty sure there are lots of fancy & elegant ways to do this. But I would think I could simply just make it an integer for future calculations?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using : oracle, mysql, sqlserver, ... ?

Comment: Aster is all I know. Should I look for more information than that?

Comment: Actually - my HUNCH is that given I am trying to alter a table that there may also be permission issues going on?

Comment: never heard of Aster before today but a quick google of Aster Datatypes gave me https://docs.tibco.com/pub/sfire-analyst/7.7.0/doc/html/en-US/TIB_sfire-analyst_UsersGuide/connectors/tera-as/tdaster_teradata_aster_data_types.htm From here it appears there is not a data type INT.  They ahve BIGINT, SMALLINT, or INTEGER try using one of these instead.

Answer (score 0):

As per [the aster docs](https://forgetcode.com/Teradata/3009/DDL-Queries), there are limited options to manipulate colums. You cannot change a column data type.

However aster allows you to change the size of a varchar column. You mentioned that you want to cast to `INTEGER`, but I guess that in your use case `VARCHAR(1)` would be fine too. If yes, then you can go :

```
ALTER TABLE a0q892.zf_predict ADD prediction VARCHAR(1);
```

If you really need an `INTEGER` (or any other type than `VARCHAR(n)`), then you have to proceed the old way :

- create a new column in the table with the correct type
- fill it from the old column
- drop the old column
- rename the new column

SQL Aster :

```
ALTER  TABLE a0q892.zf_predict ADD prediction_new int;
UPDATE TABLE a0q892.zf_predict SET prediction_new = CAST(prediction AS int);
ALTER  TABLE a0q892.zf_predict DROP prediction;
ALTER  TABLE a0q892.zf_predict RENAME prediction_new TO prediction;
```

Comment: Thank you GMB. All works, I think, except for row 2. The error is:

Executed as Single statement.  Failed [34 : 42000] [AsterData][ASTERJDBCDSII](34) ERROR: syntax error at or near "table" () 
Elapsed time = 00:00:00.281

Comment: Oh ok, there was a missing « ; » on that line, fixed it

Comment: Still not working: Executed as Single statement.  Failed [34 : 42000] [AsterData][ASTERJDBCDSII](34) ERROR: syntax error at or near "table" ()

Comment: Fixed 4th statement